# Capybara selecting root node rather than specified node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

When running locally, the code works as expected, but when running on CI server (circle CI) it behaves strangely.

I call the `#find` method passing in a `css` selector, this normally returns the specific DOM node or throws an error.

```rb
card = find('.card__title', text: display_name).ancestor('.card')
expect(card).to have_no_selector('.read')
```

On the CI server, it doesn't throw an error, rather the variable `card` has the value of:

```
#<Capybara::Node::Element tag="html" path="/HTML">
```

and the expectations fails, as it would if I wrote:

```rb
card = find(:xpath, '/html')
```

---

For the record, the return value of

```rb
card = find('.card__title', text: display_name).ancestor('.card')
```

On my local is:

```
#<Capybara::Node::Element
  tag="article"
  path="/HTML/BODY/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[2]/DIV/ARTICLE[3]">
```

---

What can possibly cause this behavior?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the same version of Capybara in both locations?