# Multiple chained finders result in selecting root node

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I need to be able to execute code on part of the page within an ancestor of an unique element.

I have the following code:

```
find('div', text: 'text').ancestor('ancestor').find('desired').click
```

and I'm sometimes getting the following error on the second or third appearance of the above line in a test case:

```
Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching visible css "desired" 
within #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="html" path="/HTML">
```

This also happens more regularly when executing the following:

```
element = find('div', text: 'text').ancestor('ancestor')
element.find('desired').click
expect(element).to have_content('stuff')
```

I can not use `first` or `all` since I think they are the cause of stale element reference error on a dynamic page. The stale element error disappears by using this.

In the second example reinitiating `element` after click does not help.

I don't know how to use ancestor with `within` and even then I would have to use within every time I switch between this element and root, which is often.

Note that this is a potential duplicate of a unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138364/capybara-selecting-root-node-rather-than-specified-node), but I created a new question because of the much newer version of capybara (I use 3.15.0) this is happening in. The issue is happening both locally and remote in this case.

EDIT: I found an example that always replicates the error:

```
element = find('example').ancestor(:css, '.ancestor')
element.find(:css, '.marked').click
puts element.path
expect(element).to have_no_css('.marked')
```

The path on line 3 will be correctly printed to console but the example will fail with the above error. If I put `sleep 2` between `puts ...` and `expect ...` there will be no error. I suppose this is not expected capybara behaviour?

Comment: This seems like a bug in Capybara with the reloading behavior of ancestor elements. What exactly does clicking on the '.marked' element do?

Comment: Makes some requests and after they are done removes the ccs '.marked'. So for as far as Capybara is concerned, executes some javascript, and removes '.marked' css after a delay. But it seems you already found the cause of this problem.

Comment: FYI: This should now be fixed in the Capybara master branch if you want to give that a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** The original issue should be fixed in the Capybara master branch as of 7/25/2019

I've confirmed there is a bug in Capybaras `ancestor` method if the node originally returned ever needs to be reloaded. You can temporarily work around that by using xpath queries rather than `ancestor` with something like

element = find('example').find(:xpath, './/ancestor::*'. class: 'ancestor')